# Mapstruct throw exception when using both Mapping with and without qualifiedByName option

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

I have an interface mapper for profile:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true))
public interface SellerProfileMapper {

@Mapping(target = "companyProfileDTO.companyProfileId", source = "id")
@Mapping(target = "companyProfileDTO.companyPicture", source = "company.picture", qualifiedByName = "buildBase64EncodingProfilePicture")
SellerProfileResponseDTO entityToSellerProfileResponseDTO(SellerProfileV2 sellerProfileV2);

@Named("buildBase64EncodingProfilePicture")
default String buildBase64EncodingProfilePicture(Image picture) {
    return ofNullable(picture)
            .map(image -> Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(image.getContent()))
            .orElse(null);
}
```

The problem is that the implementation for this mapper can only work if I remove either

`@Mapping(target = "companyProfileDTO.companyProfileId", source = "id")`

or this

`@Mapping(target = "companyProfileDTO.companyPicture", source = "company.picture", qualifiedByName = "buildBase64EncodingProfilePicture")`

then the implementation is generated! The question is why? Did I miss anything?

This is the DTO:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SellerProfileResponseDTO {
    private CompanyProfileDTO companyProfileDTO;
    private SellerProfileDTO sellerProfileDTO;
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Schema(description = "Being used as a based class for Adviser, Buyer and Seller company profile.")
public class CompanyProfileDTO {
    @Schema(description = "Company logo as a base64 img", type = "String")
    private String companyPicture;
    private String companyPictureFileName;
    private String companyProfileId;
    private String companyId;
}
```

this is the entity I want to map:

```
public class SellerProfileV2 {
    private String id;
    private String alias;
    private Company company;
...
}
```

The error that I get is:

```
Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.ma   pstruct.ap.shaded.freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
public interface SellerProfileMapper {
       ^
  ==> ext.targetBeanName  [in template "org/mapstruct/ap/internal/model/assignment/UpdateWrapper.ftl" at line 31, column 12]

  ----
  Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it.
  ----
  Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (Thes
e only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?
```

This is the generated class for the mapper:

```
@Component
public class SellerProfileMapperImpl implements SellerProfileMapper {

    @Override
    public SellerProfileResponseDTO entityToSellerProfileResponseDTO(SellerProfileV2 sellerProfileV2) {
        if ( sellerProfileV2 == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CompanyProfileDTO companyProfileDTO = null;
        CompanyProfileDTO companyProfileDTO = null;

        if ( sellerProfileV2.getCompany() != null ) {
            if ( FreeMarker template error:
                The following has evaluated to null or missing:
                ==> ext.targetBeanName  [in template "org/mapstruct/ap/internal/model/assignment/UpdateWrapper.ftl" at line 31, column 12]

                ----
                Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it.
```

Comment: Could you provide the build configuration and the `Company` class definition please ?